# CSS and JS Access Forbidden

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have deployed a lambda and also setup an API to invoke the lambda. Also my Node Express app is set to return the required CORS headers in the response. However, when I invoke the API Gateway URL the JS and CSS are blocked and so my website only gets partially rendered. Here is what I have tried so far:

But even with all those settings, when I invoke the REST API URL I see this:

[browser showing CSS and JS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGXiY.png)

1. I have explicitly configured my node app to send back the required CORS headers as per the AWS docs

```
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token');
```

2. I have enabled CORS for the API method on API-GATEWAY console
3. My node app uses cors and when I test locally it returns the right headers: see response

```
  multiValueHeaders: {
    'x-powered-by': [ 'Express' ],
    'access-control-allow-origin': [ '*' ],
    'access-control-allow-methods': [ '*' ],
    'access-control-allow-headers': [
      'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'
    ],
    'content-type': [ 'text/html; charset=utf-8' ],
```

Also I noticed that my full url to access my app has the staging name on it so `http://blah.../default/` but the url used to call to the JS and CSS does not have the staging name on it. When I copy the url and add the staging name so `http://blah../default/radar.css` for example, I get {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}.